# How to zip many blob files into one .gzip using Azure Data Factory GUI?

Tags: azure, gzip, azure-data-factory

For example

ParentFolder
   File1
   File2
   ChildFolder
       File3
       File4

to

ParentFolder.gzip

I have trouble setting up the storage sink location for the compressed blobs. The best result I get is:

File1.gzip
File2.gzip
etc...

Comment: Arrived here looking for the same: how to compress one Azure blob folder into a single file? e.g. tgz, zip or anything else as long as it's a single file

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory doesn't support Zip a folder, I think you can only connect that **Copy** activity with a custom activity to Zip it by your customized code.